# Send data from service to server (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, service, signalr

I have create 1 service and the purpose of this service is to get value from hardware and send to the server (MVC,Controller) and display the value.

The value sometime able to send to server but sometime show this error msg.

**THIS ERROR MSG GET FROM SERVICE**

> 13/8/2019 5:35:37 PM : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request..   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address,
>   String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String
>   data)    at IndicatorReadingService.Service1.Start()

I don't know what mistake that i have make.Hope you guys can helped me solved this problem thank you in advance.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string sInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Interval"];

        int iInterval;

        if(Int32.TryParse(sInterval,out iInterval))
        {
            iInterval = Int32.Parse(sInterval);
        }
        else
        {
            iInterval = 700;
        }


        timer.Interval = iInterval;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        CreateLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Start Service.");

    }

    //POST
    private void Start()
    {
         data = "NULL";
        try
        {
             data = new Indicator().StartRead();

            //var vm = new { reading = temp};
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.UploadString(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUrl"] + data), "POST");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.UploadString(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUrl"] + ex.Message), "POST");

            }

            CreateLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + ex.Message+"."+ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.UploadString` is expecting the first parameter to be the URL you are wanting to send it to, and the second to be the data. You should change your code to be:

```
client.UploadString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUrl"], data);
```